# Exception of type 'System.IO.IOException'

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I have the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Cannot locate resource 'Sections/MainWindow.xaml'.
```

I created folder and then moved my MainWindow.xaml into the folder named Sections. I got the error and then found the question that is already on here about making sure that I change my starupURI to Sections/mainwindow.xaml

However I'm still getting the error message and I don't know why.

Edit: So i ran the code again, not making any changes and now I'm getting this

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '54'.
```

The code that I have at that position:

```
<Window x:Class="CTaC_Information_System.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="CTaC Information System" Height="828" Width="1486.5" Icon="AISLogov2.ico" Loaded="Window_Loaded" FontFamily="Georgia">
```

The red line is under the `>`. I went to the end of my code and added the `</Window>` because for some reason I was still getting the error message.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Target framework in `.NET 4`

Comment: I think the second error is being caused by your icon. Try removing that bit of code and re-compiling to check if that isolates the problem. You could try changing the icon image to a .png rather than .ico

Comment: All the problems started when I moved the main window into the 'sections' folder I created in the solution explorer. I moved it back out and the errors were fixed. I'm just not sure what's going on lol

Comment: So all of the errors are gone?

Comment: After I moved everything OUT of the sections folder, however I want them in the sections folder. So yes the errors are gone but I question still remains though lol

Comment: Yep it was the name space issue! Szablocs if you post that as an answer I'll be more than happy to give you credit for answer my delima!

Comment: Have you tried to Clean and rebuild? Also somtimes the namespace doesnt get updated when you move files. Make sure the namsespace fits the path that the file is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second error is being caused by your icon. Try removing that bit of code and re-compiling to check if that isolates the problem. You could try changing the icon image to a `.png` rather than `.ico`.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happen, when i moved classes *MainWindows.xaml* and *App.xaml* from root folder to /UI folder.

When i moved them back - all become normal again, error gone.